# Identify the customers who made a rebooking within 4 weeks

Tags: mysql

For every booking on the table which is canceled. I need to check if the customer_id of the canceled booking appears with another booking within 12 weeks of the booking date.

If there exists another booking with the exact customer_id within 4 weeks after the booking date, then 1, else 0

Table 1

| customer_id | booking_date | appointment_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 | canceled |
| 2 | 02-01-2022 | completed |
| 3 | 02-01-2022 | completed |
| 4 | 10-01-2022 | canceled |
| 1 | 15-01-2022 | completed |
| 4 | 15-02-2022 | canceled |
| 4 | 17-02-2022 | completed |

Result

| customer_id | is_rebooked | booking_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01-01-2021 |
| 2 | N/a | 02-01-2022 |
| 3 | N/a | 02-01-2022 |
| 4 | 0 | 10-01-2022 |
| 1 | N/a | 15-01-2022 |
| 4 | 1 | 15-02-2022 |
| 4 | N/a | 17-02-2022 |

Since customers 1 and 4 have made a rebooking I will need to check the booking date of the next appointment is within 4 weeks if yes then 1 else 0.

Customer 2 and 3 have completed their booking therefore N/a

I would like to solve this in Mysql

Thank you

Comment: 'customer_id of the canceled booking '- The most recent cancelled booking for customer?

Comment: Hello, I have edited the table. I would like to know if there is a booking for the future for every row on the table.

Comment: Join 2 table copies by customer_id and date difference not more than 15 days then group by 1st table copy and count.

Comment: could please show how the query would be? I dont quite get it

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.customer_id, 
       t1.booking_date,
       CASE WHEN t1.appointment_status = 'completed'
            THEN 'N/a'
            ELSE COALESCE(SUM(t2.appointment_status = 'completed'), 0)
            END is_rebooked
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
                  AND t1.booking_date < t2.booking_date
                  AND t1.booking_date + INTERVAL 15 DAY >= t2.booking_date
GROUP BY t1.customer_id, t1.booking_date, t1.appointment_status
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b84c78f530964e627f20a5ac78c1cf4